# Cannot use echoping to monitor OWA login page

Tags: monitoring, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to monitor my OWA logon page using smokeping. smokeping uses echoping like this:

```
# /usr/bin/echoping -t 2 -4 -C -h /owa/auth/logon.aspx -n 20 email.charite.de
HTTP error "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized ( Der ISA Server erfordert Autorisierung, um die Anforderung durchführen zu können. Der Zugriff auf den Webserver wird v"rweigert. Wenden Sie sich an den Serveradministrator.  )
```

So, basically the page tells me I need to authenticate.
But when surfing to https://email.charite.de/owa/auth/logon.aspx I get a login page. No need to authenticate anything (yet).

Answer (score 2):

The ISA server detects valid browsers and issues a Redirect to the login page when you present what it considers a valid User-Agent string and an "401 Access Forbidden" error when you don't.

Compare the results of

```
curl -v -A "Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/60.0.3112.113"  https://email.charite.de/owa/auth/logon.aspx

curl -v  https://email.charite.de/owa/auth/logon.aspx
```

So change your `echoping` script to include a valid User-Agent string in the requests it sends.